# Excel: Count the symbol for each merged cells with different size

Tags: excel

I have a table as per below. I want to count column C "Count game win" using a formula. each person plays a different round of game within 24 hours and if he/she wins, it is label as Y. I would like to count Y using a formula but column A in merged cells contains different rows. My formula is column C is

```
=IF(A2="","",COUNTIF(B2:B3,"Y"))
```

However, when I drag down or copied to other cells, the data is wrong due to uneven size in merged cells in column A. I have a long list and will be unable to count manually. please advice
[image]

Comment: Create a helper column that repeats the name for every single row (this can be done easily with a formula), and then use COUNTIFS.

Comment: may I know how to create the helper that repeats every name from the merged cells?

Comment: In `D2`, `=IF(A2<>"",A2,D1)`, and drag down.

Comment: How to use COUNTIFS for my condition ?